# how to map using Automapper

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, automapper

I have requirement to map two objects. The requirement is train reservation details which will have towardsjourney and return journey details.

```
public class ReservationSource
{
    public string ReservationNumber{get;set;} 
    public TravelS towardsTravelS{get;set;}
    public TravelS returnTravelS{get;set;}
}
```

This is the class which is in the `ReservationSource` class  which is to capture towards and return journey details.

```
public class TravelS
{
   public string travelId{get;set;}
   public ICollection<JourneyS> Journeys{get;set;}
}
```

Above is the reservation source object. This source needs a mapping to the destination object. Destination object is given below.

```
public class ReservationDestination
{
    public string ReservationNumber{get;set;}
    public TravelD towardsTravelD{get;set;}
    public TravelD returnTravelD{get;set;}

}

public class TravelD
{
    public string travelId{get;set;}
    public ICollection<JourneyD> Journeys{get;set;}
}
public class JourneyD
{
    public string JourneyId{get;set;}
}
public class JourneyS
{
    public string JourneyId{get;set;}
}
```

This is my destination object . Here i want to map my source to destination. How do i define mapping config and map .

```
var config = new mappingConfiguration(cfg=>
{
cfg.CreateMap<ReservationSource,ReservationDestination>()
});

Imapper map = config.CreateMapper();
```

This part of code maps only the `reservationNumber` to the destination object. Can someone help me to map all objects. That is `towardsTravelS` to  `towardsTravelD` and `returnTravelS` to `returnTravelD`.

.net core version : 3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you forgot to mention this but I assume there also is a class `TravelS` that looks like this:

```
public class TravelS
{
    public string TravelId { get; set; }
}
```

There are a few things missing in your configuration. At the moment AutoMapper doesn't know it has to map properties with different names (`TowardsTravelS` => `TowardsTravelD` etc) so we have to define those aswell:

```
cfg.CreateMap<ReservationSource, ReservationDestination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ReturnTravelD, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ReturnTravelS))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.TowardsTravelD, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TowardsTravelS));
```

Here we tell AutoMapper that these properties that have different names need to be mapped.

Secondly `TravelS` and `TravelD` are different classes so we need to configure them for mapping as well:

```
cfg.CreateMap<TravelS, TravelD>();
```

So we now have something like this:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<ReservationSource, ReservationDestination>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.ReturnTravelD, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ReturnTravelS))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.TowardsTravelD, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TowardsTravelS));
    cfg.CreateMap<TravelS, TravelD>();
});

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var source = new ReservationSource
{
    ReservationNumber = "9821",
    ReturnTravelS = new TravelS
    {
      TravelId = "1"
    },
    TowardsTravelS = new TravelS
    {
      TravelId = "2"
    }
};

var destination = mapper.Map<ReservationDestination>(source);

Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(destination));
```

Output:

```
{"ReservationNumber":"9821","TowardsTravelD":{"TravelId":"2"},"ReturnTravelD":{"TravelId":"1"}}
```

Try it for yourself here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FfccVR

Comment: Thanks it worked. If i want to update few info like realtime information of the train (actual arraival/departure) ( imagine i get this from a different source), can i update the data which we have mapped through automapper. Say i have a collection/List of Travel and i need few info in travel class from a different api and after mapping all the other fields i want to update few property. Note: The collection/List is in the innerclass

Comment: Well you'll have to find the right object to update yourself. But you can map to existing objects (there is a `Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source, TDestination)` overload). This means you can chain maps from multiple source objects (or update a destination object at a later point). Just make sure that every type you use as source needs to have a configured mapping to the destination type. Good luck with the project!

Answer (score 4):

Add this in your services in startup :

it's reusable and cleaner

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
            services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
}
```

add these interface and class in your project

```
public interface IMapFrom<T>
{
        void Mapping(Profile profile) => profile.CreateMap(typeof(T), GetType());
}
```

```
using AutoMapper;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

    public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            ApplyMappingsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        }

        private void ApplyMappingsFromAssembly(Assembly assembly)
        {
                var types = assembly.GetExportedTypes()
                .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces()
                .Any(i =>i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IMapFrom<>)))
                .ToList();

            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

                var methodInfo = type.GetMethod("Mapping")
                    ?? type.GetInterface("IMapFrom`1").GetMethod("Mapping");

                methodInfo?.Invoke(instance, new object[] { this });

            }
        }
    }
```

and your source model be like this (map ReservationSource to ReservationSource):

```
 public class ReservationSource : IMapFrom<ReservationSource>
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }

        public void Mapping(Profile profile)
        {
            profile.CreateMap<ReservationSource,ReservationDestination>()
                       .ForMember(dest => dest.ReturnTravelD, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ReturnTravelS))
                       .ForMember(dest => dest.TowardsTravelD, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TowardsTravelS));
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work when use conditionally like `.ForMember(d => d.ReturnTravelD, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.ReturnTravelS != null ? s.ReturnTravelS.Where(p => p.CompletedOn.HasValue ) :
               null));`